# Changing the color of ProgressBar not working in API<21

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying the change the color of the `indeterminate` progress bar using `styles`. Added the following changes

in values/styles-v21

```
<style name="CustomHorizontalProgress" >
        <item name="android:indeterminateTint">#FF00FF</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateTintMode">src_in</item>
</style>
```

and in values/styles

```
<style name="CustomHorizontalProgress" >
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF00FF</item>
</style>
```

and set these styles in progressbar as below

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/CustomHorizontalProgress"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

For api>=21 everything this is working fine but colorAccent is not set as progress bar color in pre lollipop devices.

Note: I wanted to achieve this only using style.

Answer (score 0):

Test it

```
<style name="CustomHorizontalProgress" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" >
    <item name="android:indeterminateTint">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateTintMode">src_in</item>
```

```
<style name="CustomHorizontalProgress" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF00FF</item></style>
```

layout xml

```
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@style/CustomHorizontalProgress"
        android:theme="@style/CustomHorizontalProgress"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>

</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
progress.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: take some time to read the question clearly(especially the note) rather than copy pasting answer just to increase your reputation.